# What is the proper way to write (and source?) .pdbrc file?

Tags: python, pdb

I tried to write a `.pdbrc` file in both Python 2.7 and Python 3.5, using a sample code provided in [pdb doc](https://docs.python.org/3.2/library/pdb.html), see below:

```
# Print instance variables (usage "pi classInst")
alias pi for k in %1.__dict__.keys(): print("%1.",k,"=",%1.__dict__[k])
# Print instance variables in self
alias ps pi self
```

In my home directory, I open a file with `nano .pdbrc` and save the above code into it. Then I ran `source .pdbrc` and got the following error message:

```
-bash: .pdbrc: line 3: syntax error near unexpected token `('
-bash: .pdbrc: line 3: `alias pi for k in %1.__dict__.keys(): print("%1.",k,"=",%1.__dict__[k])'
```

How do I fix it?

Comment: The `.pdbrc` file is meant to be read by pdb. It won't make any sense to your shell.

Answer (score 2):

@Mark Plotnick commented above and actually solved this problem for me.

1. `.pdbrc` after written needs no `source .pdbrc`
2. just save `.pdbrc` in home directory, and then it is ready to use in any python files when you run `python -m pdb your_file.py`